# Meteorhacks:aggregate gives "MongoError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to aggregate some simple data and getting the total time of each person in my case. I have added the package meteorhacks:aggregate to meteor, as some guide suggested. However I can't get it to work.

This is how the documents look in the mongoDB:

```
{startnumber: 1, name: "John Doe", time: 10000}
{startnumber: 1, name: "John Doe", time: 5000}
{startnumber: 2, name: "Jane Doe", time: 11000}
```

and this is how my aggregation looks in server/main.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getTotalTime() {
    rankings.aggregate({
      $match: { startnumber: 1 },
      $group: { _id: '$name', total: { $sum: '$time' } }
    });
  }
});
```

The desired result should hopefully be:

```
{startnumber: 1, name: "John Doe", time: 15000}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now that you deleted the MIM questions I'l have to continue here. MIM's primary use is to combine existing providers, not create your own. LDAP, AD etc all have their own sync mechanism. It's *easier* to host an ADAM instance than build your own profile providers. Doing so is an advanced scenario. In any case, you can use [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) in SQL Server to retrieve only the rows that changed since a version number. It's available in all versions/editions

Comment: No idea if FIM/MIM understand it though without knowing what reference/link you used to create your provider. I *have* used FIM back in 2010 to sync AD profiles into SharePoint, yes, it was a pain, but no, I didn't use it to hit a custom profile store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each pipeline stage should be enclosed in its own document. Add a `$project` stage to format the response

```
.aggregate( 
   { $match: { startnumber: 1 } },
   { $group: { _id: '$name', startnumber:{ $first:'$startnumber' }, total: { $sum: '$time' } } },
   { $project: { name: '$_id', startnumber:1, total:1, _id:0 } }
)
```